# How to break up pdf text by number

Tags: python, regex, pdf

So my issue is not so much about pdf extraction. 
Assuming this is a pdf text extract

(a) This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text

(b) This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d)

(c) This again is is some third paragraph

Now, I am trying to create a list with 3 values, each representing a paragraph.

```py
import re
entire_text = """(a) This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text

(b) This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d) somewhere within this text

(c) This again is is some third paragraph"""
PDF_SUB_SECTIONS = ["(a) ", "(b) ", "(c) ", "(d) ", "(e) ", "(f) ", "(g) "]
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape,PDF_SUB_SECTIONS))
glSubSections = re.split(regexPattern, entire_text)
```

What I would have expected is 
['This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text',
'This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d) somewhere within this text',
'This again is is some third paragraph']

What I am getting is 
['This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text',
'This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945',
'somewhere within this text',
'This again is is some third paragraph']

More info:
1) clause 945(d) - There would never be a gap between such "945" (or any text) and "(d"
2) I am using PyPDF2 to extract text above

Comment: I am not seeing what the difference is between what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: Oh, is it that `945(d)` becomes `945`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
pattern = r'^\([a-z]\)'
re.split(pattern, entire_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

This will work but the first element of the resulting list will be an empty string. It's a little simpler than the other solution. We match the beginning of the line with `^` but in order for this to work in a string that spans multiple lines the `re.MULTILINE` flag must be pass to `re.split`. If you want to omit that bad first element just use a slice on the resulting list like so `re.split(pattern, entire_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)[1:]`.

For more info about the that `re.MULTILINE` thing see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this with regular expressions, but usually it would get more complicated than that, likely not the best way. For instance, with an expression similar to:

```
^(?:\([^)]+\))\s*(.*)
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?:\([^)]+\))\s*(.*)"

test_str = ("(a) This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text\n\n"
    "(b) This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d)\n\n"
    "(c) This again is is some third paragraph")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

#### Output

```
['This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text', 'This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d)', 'This again is is some third paragraph']
```

#### Test with `re.sub`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?:\([^)]+\))\s*(.*)"

test_str = ("(a) This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text\n\n"
    "(b) This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d)\n\n"
    "(c) This again is is some third paragraph")

subst = "\\1"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE))
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?:\([^)]+\))\s*(.*)"

test_str = ("(a) This is my first paragraph, which is some junk text\n\n"
    "(b) This is another paragraph, but it incidentally has some reference to another paragraph which refers to clause 945(d)\n\n"
    "(c) This again is is some third paragraph")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdnZt0/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jdnZt0/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]